# Java schedule runs only once

Tags: java, scheduler

I have a task that I want to run every sunday at 6 pm, and Ive used javax.ejb.Schedule for this purpose. Ive set the schedule as;

```
@Schedule(dayOfWeek = "Sun", hour="18", persistent = false)
```

For some reason this only runs once and then quietly stops. If I annotate it as the following it goes ahead and runs every minute;

```
@Schedule(hour="*", minute="*", persistent = false)
```

I know that if an exception is thrown the timer is purged, but when I run it every minute it works fine. Also, the first sunday it runs fine and then I see no trace of it the second sunday; no exception or logging or anything.
Any thoughts? More code;

```
@Schedules(value = { 
        @Schedule(dayOfWeek = "Sun", hour="18", persistent = false)
        })
public void runTask() {

    logger.info("Running task");
    File file = new File("file.csv");
    List<String[]> data = getData();
    try {
        populateCsv(file, data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error creating csv file", e);
    }
}

private void populateCsv(File file, List<String[]> data) throws IOException {
    CSVWriter csvWriter = null;
    try {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        csvWriter = new CSVWriter(fileWriter, ',', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
        csvWriter.writeAll(data);
    } finally {
        if (csvWriter != null) {
            csvWriter.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The @Schedules annotation is there for historic reasons, just wanted to keep the code accurate when posting here

Comment: Have you tried to debug to see what exactly is happening? If you put a breakpoint in your method you can run up the stack to see which Java class is calling your method and why it may or may not be rescheduling.

Comment: my guess will be there you are setting `persistent` to be false, try set it to be true and run again

Comment: The problem is that if I want to debug Ill set it to Tue (as its tuesday today) and it will work one time without problems, no exceptions thrown. Then Id have to wait a week...
If I set it to dayOfWeek="Tue", hour="*", minute="*" to debug more than once itll work fine all day. Im thinking its something with the defaults, like setting minute="*" will give you every minute with hour defaulting to midnight

Answer (score 0):

Try giving dayOfMonth="Sun",month="*",year="*",hour="18" as parameters and verify.

Comment: Ill try this, am thinking it probably has something to do with the default values altough I cant find any info on the defaulting values

Comment: Last week I deployed a version like this and it didn't run at all;
@Schedule(year="*", month="*", dayOfWeek = "Sun", hour="18", persistent = false)

Comment: please remove those month and year attributes and instead of dayOfWeek..use dayOfMonth and try.I think it'll work :/